# JSON treatement

Tags: json, encode

I have a problem to treat the JSON array in my program.
I call a function `echo json_encode(['MyData' => $donnees] );`
and in the consol log my object seems ok but it seems that i am blocked inside, as when i had something after this line my object is not anymore valid and seems that the encode function want to add the next instruction into the array.So if i write
`echo json_encode(['MyData' => $donnees] ); echo 'Why i don't get out ?';`
My consol log show
"{"MyData":[{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 13:00:00","Moy1":"0.58","Moy2":"25.36","Moy3":"23.45"},{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 13:30:00","Moy1":"0.58","Moy2":"24.59","Moy3":"22.66"},{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 14:00:00","Moy1":"0.58","Moy2":"24.43","Moy3":"22.04"},{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 14:30:00","Moy1":"1.63","Moy2":"23.50","Moy3":"21.30"},{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 15:00:00","Moy1":"1.62","Moy2":"24.97","Moy3":"23.42"},{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 15:30:00","Moy1":"1.67","Moy2":"26.20","Moy3":"24.98"},{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 16:00:00","Moy1":"1.21","Moy2":"26.91","Moy3":"26.43"},{"MoyDate":"2022-11-12 16:30:00","Moy1":"1.24","Moy2":"26.21","Moy3":"25.69"}]}Why i don't get out ?\t\r\n"
If someone have an idea please.

Comment: That second echo statement is not in the json object, nor in the array. It written after it, so I don't see a problem here

Comment: Ok i understand your point. I just learn about Ajax/Json and it's not easy. I succed to pass it as i want from the .php file with this : ````$jsonData = json_encode($donnees);
echo $jsonData;```` but i don't understand how to read them and slice the array.When i try this : ````const citrus = $jsonData.slice(1, 3);```` i get an error from log as follow Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined

Comment: The *contents* of a json string is an *object* (hence the `{}` outer brackets), it is not an array, but it may contain them. Now that you've encoded it it is just a regular string. So, you encoded it, passed it, and now you can decode it into a PHP class - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php to access the data in it

Comment: Or are you trying to reference it in JavaScript?

Comment: Hi @KScandrett not understood all but I want to use this in a js script and I succeed to get in the variable result and now I want to slice it in 3 different array.

Comment: `$jsonData["MyData"].slice(1, 3)`